# Directshow AVI File length doesn't match recorded time

Tags: directshow, avi

I am using directshow to record 1920x1080 60fps from a avermedia live gamer portable 2 plus to avi file.  When I go to play back the file, the length is always longer than I have recorded.  For example record 20 seconds, file shows 28 seconds.

I have tried timestamping events using gettickcoun64 to give me a relative elapsed time, and I have also used the AVIMUX IMediaSeeking GetCurrentPosition function.  Both correlate well to each other and to the actual elapsed time.  However when I open the file after completing recording the file always seems to be longer.

[image: Basic Filter Graph which gives invalid file length]

The filter graph is very basic with just the capture device, audio capture device, AVIMUX and a file writer.

I have tried removing the audio and get the same result, 28 seconds instead of 20.

If I reduce the frame rate to 50fps, the times match.  If I reduce the image size 1280 x 768 60fps the files do not match, seem to be related to AVI file and 60fps?

Interestingly if I look at the file with MediaInfo it says the file is only 20 seconds long (Which is what I would expect) but load in windows media player or Directshow player and they say 28 seconds.

[image: Media Info analysis]

Comment: Seems to be something to do with MJPEG, if I record H264 1920x1080 60fps this is the correct length, MJPEG 18=920x1080 is always the wrong length.

Comment: You could probably find more artifacts analyzing the AVI file, such as for example many dropped frames (for those extra 8 seconds). However in order to troubleshoot there is insufficient data in the question. You could attach a full topology of the filter graph and a sample recording, to start with.

Comment: @Roman  I have uploaded file to https://ulozto.net/!3fEL9yXh5TaX/test-avi this is 20 seconds of real video but file is 28 seconds.  On home PC I have avermedia AVI Mux, if i replace the standard windows AVI MUX with this in the filter graph, file is the correct size.

Comment: It's something with frame time stamping. Most likely small time fluctuations remap a frame to later time in terms of fixed FPS and hence you have lots of "dropped frames" and extended time.